# What is React Implementation of Android ViewModel

Tags: reactjs, mvvm

I'm An Android Developer, but recently I'm working on a React project.
So what is React implementation of Android ViewModel?

I found some articles talk about redux but it doesn't seem to be the same thing

Comment: The usage of patterns such as MVVM is situational, and in my personal opinion, the "general" architecture of React applications does not immediately make MVVM pattern a good fit. That's why you're having a hard time finding resources on the subject

Comment: @nbokmans okay what do you suggest me to use?

Answer (score 0):

`React` is fundamentally different than an object oriented language, where mutability is standard. In React, data is `Immutable`. As the framework has evolved, other components and libraries are being made to make it easier to handle data, but they don't replace a well designed app architecture (and are overly complicated in my opinion).

For example, to update a singular item in a Redux store, you have to first make a copy of the entire object, find the thing you want to update and change it. Then re-assign the copied object and send that to the server. This is due to the data being Immutable. That seems like a lot of work just to update a variable, right?

In my opinion, the correct way to use React would be in an application that doesn't require a lot of transferring and saving of data on the front-end (from user interaction) before pushing it back up to the database.

If you're like me, and you love Object Oriented programming and you would like to have a data model you can interact with locally (because you don't need to constantly update the server), then perhaps choose a language like Angular.

Angular is much more friendly to Mutable data, and you can much more easily create things akin to a ViewModel in Android. I've been on a React kick recently to see what all the hub-bub is about, but I'm not personally impressed. I think it is getting used just because it's popular, not because it's the right tool for the job.

I agree with the sentiment early on in React's age that they called it a Library. While I think it's current state reflects more of a framework, If you treat it as a front-end library on top of a data oriented back-end, I think React still has a place in the web ecosystem. I'm not really sure what would go good with it though, and how that development experience would be like. (It could be god awful or an amazing experience for all I know)